# Limit of exponent that does not diverge in $1/x^n$

Tags: integration, analysis

The integral of $1/x$ diverges, as the function grows quick enough.

The integral of $1/x^2$ converges to $π^2/6$ since it grows slowly enough for it to converge.

Is there a number $n$ for which the integral of $1/x^n$ is diverging to infinity but for any $n+ε$, it converges?

Basically, where is the boundary between divergent and convergent $1/x^n$ functions?

Comment: $\int_0^1 x^\alpha\,dx<\infty$ if and only if $\alpha>-1$. $\int_1^\infty x^\alpha\,dx<\infty$ if and only if $\alpha<-1$. These assertions can be checked by just computing the antiderivative of $x^\alpha$.

Comment: Yes, and that number is $1$. To be clear, we’re talking about for example $\int_1^{\infty}$ here. If lower bound is $0$, it’s different.

Comment: Btw, is the *sum* of $1/x^2$ that gives $\pi^2/6$, not the integral. That is, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/n^2 = \pi^2/6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral of $1/x^n$ towards infinity, converges exactly if $n>1$, as then
$$ \int_1^\infty 1/x^n\,dx = \lim_{x\to\infty} (1-n)^{-1}x^{1-n} - (1-n)^{-1}1 = -(1-n)^{-1}$$
But for $n\leq 1$ we get something divergent. Similarly, the integral towards $0$ converges iff $n<1$.

Thus $1$ is the boundary you are talking about.

Comment: You should divide by $1-n$ and not multiply.

Comment: @Gary Sorry, yes. Skipped the $^{-1}$ there...